# Generate Set from Array with the bounds

Tags: ruby

I want to know is some sort of "Array.to_range" method in order to create some Range from an Array of two elements.
I know that i could perform something like this:

```
a = [1,5]
Set.new(a[0]..a[1])
 => #<Set: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}>
```

This a good solution, however i try to synthesize more, to archive something like this:

```
a = [1,5]
Set.new(a.to_range)
```

because if i do this, generate a Set with only 2 elements and i want the full range of elements.

```
a = [1,5]
Set.new(a)
 => #<Set: {1, 5}>
```

and obviously

```
{1, 5} != {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

So, any idea how can i synthesize this expression more?

```
Set.new(a[0]..a[1])
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! `Set.new(a[0]..a[1])` -- what's wrong with that and what do you mean by "synthesizing" it more?

Comment: I'm trying to generate more, dynamic code! Avoiding hardcoding things like the boundaries  you know `a[0]..a[1]` basically its redundant because i already know that is an Array with 2 elements, that why a create a instead of making something like `start_bound = 0, end_bound = 5`. Basically im using  `Array.minmax` to sort bounds im trying to re-use that line. Heading to something like `Set.new(Array.minmax)` and get a Set with all elements between the bounds.

Comment: Not sure I follow. A range has a start and endpoint, so if you're guaranteed an array of pairs you're using to represent the range, I don't think it's hardcoding to pick out the two elements specifically, and in fact the code is quite clear to a casual reader. If you want some additional abstraction, the spec seems unclear. What is `[0, 3, 2]` supposed to represent (or some other array that isn't a pair)?

Comment: synthesizing -> Array of two elements to Range in simple expression.  I prefer to stick with `a[0]..a[1]` to use some sort of block or attach that functionality to Array class.

Comment: OK, then what's stopping you from adding the `to_range` to the array class?

Comment: I'm looking for weird tricks in Rubyist language, people sometimes know dark things. And also i think it's too much for one time use and `Set.new(a[0]..a[1])` doesn't seem to ugly rather that the number of lines i need to achieve Array.to_range

Comment: "I'm looking for weird tricks in Rubyist language, people sometimes know dark things" -- sounds pretty unmaintainable...

Comment: What you think ?
`Set.new(a.min..a.max)
 => #<Set: {1, 2, 3, 4}>`
or 
`Set.new(Range.new(*a))
 => #<Set: {1, 2, 3, 4}> `

Comment: Neither seems clearer than `Set.new(a[0]..a[1])` which is direct and obvious. The `Range` version is good since the error makes more sense when your array is the wrong size. To each their own. It's a pretty minor decision.

Comment: Superficially, i can count `Set.new` , `a.min` , `a.max` ,` .. ` 4 operations. While `Set.new` , `Range.new` ,` *a`, 3 operations and also dynamic generation of objects. `Set.new(a.min..a.max)` looks ambiguous, hardcoded. At least that's what i think, but anyway thanks for the help pal!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this give you what you are looking for:

```rb
a = [1,5]

Set.new(Range.new(*a)) # =>  #<Set: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}>
```

Comment: Thanks pal! The trick i was looking for was `*a` part!

Comment: This is preferable to `Set.new(Range.new(a.first, a.last))`? Not in my book. `Range.new(a.first, a.last)` tells me exactly how the range is constructed from  the array `a`. If I see `Range.new(*a)`, I'd think "that's odd" and then make sure `a` contains exactly two elements. My criticism is not of the answer, but of the question.

Comment: Past: 
`a = Array.minmax
Set.new(a[0]..a[1])`
Present: 
`Set.new(Range.new(*Array.minmax))` looks better ? `Array.minmax` returns an array  of two elements and i don't need store that, so i try to reuse that line and save memory and trash lines of code.

Comment: And i'm not sure, but i think i just need the copy of the object generated rather than the complete instance and lifecycle of the reference object . I know get the idea of `Range.new(a.first, a.last)` looks a little bit cleaner. I'm just trying so save tha `a = OtherArray.minmax` part because i'm gonna rerune this lines like a lot of times.

Comment: Julian, firstly, `minmax` is not an instance method of `Array`, so `Array.minmax` will raise an exception. If you mean `Set.new(Range.new(*a.minmax))`, suppose `a #=> [2,1]` due to a bug in your code. Then `Set.new(Range.new(*a.minmax))
#=> #<Set: {1, 2}>`, which hides the bug. Focus on clarity, even if it means a few extra characters here and there. If you want to save some form of `a`, maybe you could make it a range or hash in the first place: `1..5` or `{ start: 1, end: 5 }`.